# Stellar JS / Trigger function at certain height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using stellar JS (http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) to put together a parallax scrolling site for Ipad, I would like to trigger a function at a certain height (to animate a slide from the right of the screen) - has anyone had expereince of monitoring for a screen height position and triggering a function - either using stellar.js or in general.

Cheers
paul

Comment: To clarify: are you looking to trigger the event based off of the relative stellar.js parallax height, or the absolute height based off of the screen?

Comment: I think either would allow me to acheieve what I'm after (fade in effects and movement from right).  cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggering a function once you scroll to a certain height is pretty doable with a bit of jQuery - here's some simple code to do it:

```
function scrollHeightTrigger (height, fn) {
  var old_height = $(document).scrollTop();
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    var new_height = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (((height < new_height) && (height >= old_height)) ||
        ((height < old_height) && (height >= new_height))) {
      fn();
    }
    old_height = new_height;
  });
}
```

scrollHeightTrigger takes a height and a function - the height specifies at what scroll distance from the top the function should be triggered. This is done by remembering what the previous height from the top the document was, then checks every time the user scrolls if they've passed the target. If they have, the function is fired.

As-is, this will repeat the function every time the scroll location is passed - if you want a single execution though, it shouldn't be too hard to modify.

Comment: spot on - cheers Bubbles, though I dont suppose you'd know how to get this to work on an Ipad would you!?

Comment: You may also be interested to look at the 'Waypoints' plugin: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/